# Inlcude TTFB to the response header

Tags: apache

Is it possible to include TTFB in the response header? It can be added to the logs by using module mod_logio:

%^FB -> Delay in microseconds between when the request arrived and the first byte of the response headers are written

So when enabled, I can see it appears in the logs but when I try adding it to response header I got an error:

```
Header set MyHeader "Hello Joe. It took %^FB microseconds for Apache to serve first byte"
```

Apache failed to restart:

```
Apr 09 07:01:05 ip-172-31-57-64.ec2.internal httpd[176193]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 177 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:
Apr 09 07:01:05 ip-172-31-57-64.ec2.internal httpd[176193]: Unrecognized header format %^
```